# Why php sorting my Images different on different Platforms

Tags: php, sorting, directory

This code does what it should on Xampp (Storting the images in a alphabetically order), but if i uploaded it on a Hosting service it randomly orders.

I tried already natsort(); but maybe i implemented it wrong.
I tried scandir but i doesent find the images (tried to change the path into the rootpath doesent worked either)

```
<?php 
$path = "./upload/outdoor/server/php/files/";
$dh = opendir($path);
$i=1;
while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
  if($file != "." && $file != ".gitignore" && $file != "thumbnail" && $file != ".." && $file != "index.php" && $file != ".htaccess" && $file != "error_log" && $file != "cgi-bin") {
    //Image Output
    echo "<div>
    <div href='$path/$file'>
    <img src='$path/$file' />
    </div>
    </div>";
    $i++;}
  } 
closedir($dh);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

## This works and orders the Images as i would expected. Example (01_Image, 02_Image, 03_Image are now in the first second and third place in the gallery)

```
  <?php 
  $path = "./upload/art/server/php/files/";
  $ignore = array('.', '..', '.gitignore', 'thumbnail', 'index.php', '.htaccess');
  $i=1;

  $files = scandir($path);
  foreach($files as $file){
  if(!in_array($file, $ignore)) {

    //Image Output
    echo "<div>
     <img src='$path/$file' />
     </div>
     </div>";
     $i++;
    }
   }
```

?>